# Find Slanted Horizontal Asymptote for equation $\frac{6x^3-5x}{3x^2+4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I know I am looking to find a slanted horizontal asymptote because I can see $6x^3$ is in the numerator and is one degree more than $3x^2$.  The method, in the book, to find the equation of the slanted asymptote is to use synthetic division.  Not sure how to use the book's way because I keep finding imaginary numbers for factors.  Since I am looking at only real numbers in the domain, I feel like I am really lost.

When I evaluate the denominator of $\frac{6x^3-5x}{3x^2+4}$ I get: $$3x^2+4=0$$ $$3x^2=-4$$$$x^2=-\frac43$$$$x=\pm\sqrt{-\frac43}$$$$x=\pm\frac{2i\sqrt3}{3}$$

I don't think I can synthetic divide with imaginary numbers, also I don't think these numbers are in the domain of the function.  I really am wondering what I can do to find the asymptote?
thanks

Comment: You don't have to factorise the denominator to linear polynomials before division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the function is defined for all real $x$, as you have shown. Take the limit to infinity to find the asymptote:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{6x^3-5x}{3x^2+4} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{6x-5/x}{3+4/x^2} = \ ?$$

Without calculus, you can write:

$$6x^3 - 5x = 2x(3x^2 + 4) - 13x$$

and now divide by $3x^2+4$ on both sides.

Comment: would you mind helping me find the equation $6x^3-5x=2x(3x^2+4)-13x$. I do not know Calculus.

Comment: @Benp404 That can be done using long division. No need for calculus. [Just realized you may not have thought calculus was needed, Anyway do the long division to get quotient and remainder.

Comment: Yes, that is long division as $3x^2$ goes into $6x^3$ $2x$ times.

Comment: Thanks.  If I do a little bit of research on long division I should be set.  The polynomials aren’t exactly in order.  Some of the terms are missing, but I do know how to do long division.  Thank you so much.